# Parent logger with level lower than child's

Tags: python, python-logging

It's a common practice for a package to define a logger for the top level and have every sub module taking a child logger by `logging.getLogger(__name__)`.

### The problem: Parent logger has level lower than child's.

I want to disable DEBUG logs from `package.module` specifically but to keep the overall log level to be DEBUG. I tried to something like so -

```py
logging.config.dictConfig({
  "loggers": {
     "package": {
        "level": "DEBUG",
        "handlers": ["console"],
      },
      "package.module": {
         "level": "INFO"
      }
  }
})
```

However this does not work as I'd expect and as long as the child logger propagates its logs, DEBUG logs will be outputted by the parent.

What can I do here to block certain levels of child only?
I could set propagate to False but that will block the logs completely which is not desirable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me, "debug" messages to "package" are emitted while those to "package.module" are not:

```py
import logging, logging.config

logging.config.dictConfig({
    'version': 1,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        }
    },
    "loggers": {
        'root': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
        },
        "package": {
            "level": "DEBUG",
        },
        "package.module": {
            "level": "INFO"
        }
    }
})


logging.getLogger('package').debug("should be emitted")
logging.getLogger('package.module').debug("should not be emitted")
```

Loggers should filter messages *at intake*, so as per the documentation when logging a message it will be ignored if its level is below the logger's *effective level*, and a logger's effective level is the first level other than `NOTSET` found when traversing from the logger to the root of the loggers tree. If the traversal doesn't find anything then the effective level is `NOTSET` and all messages are emitted (even those below `DEBUG`).

However this means that if descendants of `package.module` are configured back to `DEBUG` that will override `package.module`. This is an important concept: the level of a logger is an *intake filter*, once a record has been accepted they're not a consideration anymore.

The use-case for `propagate` is rather different, it's to be used when you configure "emitting" handlers at intermediate levels of the tree (otherwise the record will be emitted multiple times).

Comment: Actually it seems to be all good for as well, I think that in my actual code the important understanding was for when the level is `NOTSET` which as you said emits everything

Comment: If `package` level is INFO and `package.module` is DEBUG, the sub module still not emitting

Comment: @LuisComS works fine for me. If I take the script above and just swap INFO and DEBUG in the configuration, then it prints "should not be emitted" which is what I would expect.

Comment: You are right, my problem was caused because I was using `yaml` package to configure, so when I load a yaml to configure logging it do not stay with `dot notation`, the library transform the `yaml` to `dict` with hierarchy

Comment: I just create this algorithim to test this behaviour https://gist.github.com/luiscoms/b5b64001fb2675a9039a63eaebc212b8